# Rectilinear motion

Tags: calculus, derivatives, physics

What is the initial position of a particle moving in a parabola according to the equation x(t) = sqrt (t^2 -25) , x in meters, t in seconds?

Answer (score 0):

The initial position is simply the position at $t=0$. In this case you can see that for $t=0$, $x$ is not real ($5i$), which tells us that this equation can not physically describe a particle's position.